# MySQL update multiple tables with indirect where statements

Tags: mysql, wordpress

To give you context, this problem resides within a WordPress site, but is not WP related.

I am essentially trying to change values in two tables that are tied together.

Table #1 is `wp_term_taxonomy` (hereby `TT`) with the following columns:

term_taxonomy_id | term_id | taxonomy | description | parent

The following statement updates `TT.taxonomy` and `TT.parent` properly.

```
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy TT
SET 
    TT.taxonomy='industry',
    TT.parent=0
WHERE TT.taxonomy='project_categories' 
    AND TT.parent=276;
```

This is changing the `taxonomy` column to a new value for anything previously under a specific parent.

What I need to do is also alter another table which has ties to this one.

It's called `wp_icl_translations` (hereby `ICL`), and has the following columns:

translation_id | element_type | element_id | ...

There are two intersections between these tables:

- `TT.term_id` is an intersection with `ICL.element_id`
- `TT.taxonomy` is an intersection with `ICL.element_type`, where the value of `ICL.element_type` is also prefixed by `tax_`.

My expectation was that the following statement would update:

- `TT.parent`
- `TT.taxonomy`
- `ICL.element_type`

This is my attempted SQL statement

```
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy TT, wp_icl_translations ICL
SET 
    TT.taxonomy='industry',
    TT.parent=0,
    ICL.element_type = 'tax_industry'
WHERE TT.taxonomy='project_categories' 
    AND TT.parent=276
    AND ICL.element_id=TT.term_taxonomy_id
    AND ICL.element_type='tax_project_categories';
```

I need both `ICL.element_id` and `ICL.element_type` checked within the where statement, as there can be duplicate `element_id` entries for different `element_type`'s.

Comment: I'm not understanding the **question** you are asking. A few notes about your attempted SQL statement: the dot preceding the table name isn't valid (looks like the database qualifier was removed). We prefer to use the `JOIN` keyword in place of the old-school comma syntax, and have the join predicates in an `ON` clause. Since this is performing an inner join, rows in `TT` will only be updated if a matching row exists in `ICL`, maybe you want an outer join. (I'm just guessing.) What exactly was the question?

Comment: Yes, I removed the database at the last minute, updating the question. There was an issue with the where statement and getting matched rows. Adding the `ICL.element_type` in removed matches. The answer you and Nico provided solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work.

```
UPDATE .wp_term_taxonomy TT
INNER JOIN .wp_icl_translations ICL ON ICL.element_id = TT.term_id
                                   AND ICL.element_type='tax_project_categories'
SET 
    TT.taxonomy='industry',
    TT.parent=0,
    ICL.element_type = 'tax_industry'
WHERE TT.taxonomy='project_categories' 
  AND TT.parent=276
```

Answer (score 1):

(As I indicated in the comment on your question, I'm not exactly sure what question you are asking. I'm just guessing.)

It sounds like you want a join predicate like this:

```
   ICL.element_type = CONCAT('tax_',TT.taxonomy)
```

If you want to update rows in `TT` even if there are no matching rows in `ICL`, you can use an outer join. (If that's not the case, and you only want to update row in `TT` if a matching row exists in `ICL`, just remove the `LEFT` keyword.)

For example:

```
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy TT
  LEFT
  JOIN wp_icl_translations ICL
    ON ICL.element_type = CONCAT('tax_',TT.taxonomy)
   AND ICL.element_id   = TT.term_id

   SET TT.parent        = 0
     , TT.taxonomy      = 'industry'
     , ICL.element_type = CONCAT('tax_','industry')

 WHERE TT.taxonomy = 'project_categories' 
   AND TT.parent = 276
```